# Why is Firefox not trusting my self-signed certificate?

Tags: ssl, firefox, certificate, keychain, trust

I have a local domain (`markfisher.local`) for which I have made a self-signed certificate that I have added to the Certificates in Keychain Access (I am using Mac). This results in the certificate being trusted in Chrome and Safari. If I edit the certificates Trust in KeyChain Access to "Never Trust" then Chrome and Safari no longer accept it, then if I change it back to "Always Trust" then I can access `markfisher.local` OK again.

But when accessing the site in Firefox I get the following:

```
markfisher.local uses an invalid security certificate.
The certificate does not come from a trusted source.
Error code: MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_CA_CERT_USED_AS_END_ENTITY
```

I have set `security.enterprise_roots.enabled` to `true` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44789243/3578997). Also, going to Preferences > Privacy & Security > View Certificates, I can see my certificate is in the Authorities tab and I have checked the "This certificate can identify websites" in the "Edit Trust" dialog. This was not checked originally

However Firefox refuses to accept the certificate. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1034124 and specifically this answer:

> Looks like that certificate has a basicConstraints extension with the
> value cA: TRUE. We stopped allowing CA certificates to act as
> end-entity certificates. That certificate should be regenerated
> without the basicConstraints extension.

This is also explained at https://wiki.mozilla.org/SecurityEngineering/x509Certs

> Error Code: MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_CA_CERT_USED_AS_END_ENTITY
>
> What It Means: A certificate with a basic constraints extension with cA:TRUE is being used as an end-entity certificate
>
> What Can I Do: Re-generate the end-entity certificate without the basic constraints extension

Comment: I tried that, and now I get SEC_ERROR_BAD_SIGNATURE in Firefox. Chrome and Safari are still fine.

Comment: SEC_ERROR_BAD_SIGNATURE should really mean the certificate is malformed. Except trying to generate some more, differently, I have no idea. Make sure to generate "v3" certificates, not v1 ones. Alternatively, post the certificate content in your question so anyone could see it.

Comment: I think I altered the basicConstraints config setting in the wrong section first time around. I fixed the MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_CA_CERT_USED_AS_END_ENTITY with your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Using [devcert](https://github.com/davewasmer/devcert) you can generate a self-signed cert and it will work with Firefox.

Comment: But then the certificate can't be installed on Android - only CA certificates can be installed

Answer (score 15):

This answer is expanding on [Patrick Mevzek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59739121/1498178). To quote:

> See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1034124 and
> specifically this answer:
>
> > Looks like that certificate has a basicConstraints extension with the
> > `value cA: TRUE`. We stopped allowing CA certificates to act as
> > end-entity certificates. That certificate should be regenerated
> > without the `basicConstraints` extension.
>
> This is also explained at
> https://wiki.mozilla.org/SecurityEngineering/x509Certs
>
> > Error Code: `MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_CA_CERT_USED_AS_END_ENTITY`
> >
> > What It Means: A certificate with a basic constraints extension with `cA:TRUE` is being used as an end-entity certificate
> >
> > What Can I Do: Re-generate the end-entity certificate without the basic constraints extension

---

In short, to use self-signed SSL certificates to work in Firefox (e.g., for testing HTTPS), you'll have to go the long route of creating and using your own public key infrastructure (PKI):

##### Step 1. Establish your private *certificate authority* (CA)

By creating a *private key* and *self-signed certificate*:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes \
  -newkey RSA:2048       \
  -keyout root-ca.key    \
  -days 365              \
  -out root-ca.crt       \
  -subj '/C=US/ST=Denial/L=Earth/O=Atest/CN=root_CA_for_firefox'
```

Generated files:

- `root-ca.key`: The private key of your CA
- `root-ca.crt`: The x509 certificate of your CA ([signed with `root-ca.key`](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/240560/does-signing-of-csr-by-the-same-private-key-create-self-signed-certificate)).

##### Step 2. Create a *private key* and a *certificate signing request* (CSR) for your server

```
openssl req -nodes   \
  -newkey rsa:2048   \
  -keyout server.key \
  -out server.csr    \
  -subj '/C=US/ST=Denial/L=Earth/O=Dis/CN=anything_but_whitespace'
```

Generated files:

- `server.key`: Private key
- `server.csr`: Certificate signing request; does not any domain names to be specified.

##### Step 3. Generate a certificate for your server

> NOTE
> Make sure to use the right domain name at the `subjectAltName = DNS:<domain>` part below!

```
openssl x509 -req    \
  -CA root-ca.crt    \
  -CAkey root-ca.key \
  -in server.csr     \
  -out server.crt    \
  -days 365          \
  -CAcreateserial    \
  -extfile <(printf "subjectAltName = DNS:localhost\nauthorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer\nbasicConstraints = CA:FALSE\nkeyUsage = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment\nextendedKeyUsage=serverAuth")
```

<sup>The `<(..)` part is called [process substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) in Bash. If you use another shell without this feature, then simply put the text inside the double quotes in a file, replace "\n" with newlines, and specify the file instead for `-extfile`.</sup>

Generated files:

- `root-ca.srl`: I usually ignore it
- `server.crt`: Certificate to be used on your server

##### Step 4. Add `root-ca.crt` to Firefox's trust store

By following [these steps](https://javorszky.co.uk/2019/11/06/get-firefox-to-trust-your-self-signed-certificates/).

> NOTE
> As @sstchur pointed out in the comments, this step may not be necessary if the options
>
> - `security.certerrors.mitm.auto_enable_enterprise_roots` and
> - `security.enterprise_roots.enabled`
>
> are set to `true`. (See the Mozilla support article [How to disable the Enterprise Roots preference](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-disable-enterprise-roots-preference) for details.)
> (**subnote**: I didn't have the time to test these yet in practice!)

##### Step 5. Configure your server

You'll need `server.key` and `server.crt`. The specific steps depend on the technology.

---

### Why are these steps needed for Firefox?

While the following one-liner below works both in Chrome and Safari,

<sup>(That is, where one would use the created cert both as a root CA cert (to install in a system's trust store) and a cert for a web server (e.g., in NGINX with `ssl_certificate`).)</sup>

```
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes                                            \
  -newkey RSA:2048                                                       \
  -days 365                                                              \
  -subj '/C=US/ST=Denial/L=Springfield/O=Dis/CN=anything_but_whitespace' \
  -addext 'subjectAltName = DNS:doma.in,DNS:anoth.er'                    \
  -addext 'authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer'                        \
  -addext 'basicConstraints = CA:FALSE'                                  \
  -addext 'keyUsage = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment'                 \
  -addext 'extendedKeyUsage=serverAuth'                                  \
  -out self-signed.crt                                                   \
  -keyout private.key
```

it won't in Firefox, because:

1. You can't install `self-signed.crt` in Firefox's trust store, because it explicitly states that the certificate is **not** a certificate authority (`CA:FALSE`).
2. **What if you change `CA:FALSE` to `CA:TRUE` in the command above?**

   Chrome and Safari will still accept it, you can install `self-signed.crt` into Firefox's trust store, but it won't work from the server's side because of the quoted reasons at the top of this answer.
3. **What if you simply delete the `-addext 'basicConstraints = CA:FALSE` option?**

   Firefox will complain when trying to import `self-signed.crt` in its trust store:

   [image: Alert: This is not a certificate authority certificate, so it can’t be imported into the certificate authority list.]

   (Probably because of the x509 v3 extensions added with `-addext`.)
4. **What if you omit all the x509 v3 extensions (i.e., `-addext` options)?**

   ```
   openssl req -x509 -new -nodes                                            \
     -newkey RSA:2048                                                       \
     -days 365                                                              \
     -subj '/C=US/ST=Denial/L=Springfield/O=Dis/CN=anything_but_whitespace' \
     -out self-signed.crt                                                   \
     -keyout private.key
   ```

   Now you can import `self-signed.crt` into Firefox's trust store, but you will get `SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN` (and you'll get a similar error in Chrome and Safari as [they need the `subjectAltName` extension](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/271698/120885) to be present on the certificate from the server's side).
5. **What about changing the command to contain `CN=<your domain>`?**

   You'll probably still get the same error as "*[Firefox from 101.0 onward no longer uses certificate CN (Common Name) for matching domain name to certificate and have migrated to only using SAN (Subject Alternate Name)](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1379144#answer-1510601)*".

   Which means you have to add at least the `subjectAltName` x509 v3 extension, but then you are back at items 1, 2, or 3 above.

Comment: Why is Step 5: Configure your server needed?
Firefox has a setting, security.certerrors.mitm.auto_enable_enterprise_roots, which is default set to true.  I thought that setting caused Firefox to automatically import OS-level enterprise roots?  So if I install the cert into the Windows Trust Root Certification Authorities store, why doesn't Firefox auto enable it, like the setting suggests it would?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question because I'm not familiar with any of those settings. I put this answer together because I had the same issue as the OP when serving a web app on my local machine and trying to enable HTTPS for Firefox. So, for me, step 5. was to configure the cert bundle and the server's private key for NGINX that would be serving the site itself. What was your specific issue that led you to this thread?

Comment: Yes, I had the same issue as the OP with Firefox not trusting the self-signed cert.  I followed your instructions to establish a CA, create a CSR and then generate a new cert signed by the CA.  And that works if you manually import it into Firefox's cert store.  Apparently FF has its own cert store apart from the Windows cert store.

But Firefox has a setting: `security.certerrors.mitm.auto_enable_enterprise_roots`, which I understood was supposed to automatically import trusted root certs into the FF store. I was hoping that would alleviate the need for me to manually import the cert to FF

Comment: doh! I’m sorry! I see I confused the issue because I incorrectly said step 5, when I meant step 4. Why is step 4 needed?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications! I updated my answer, but didn't have the time to test these settings yet, and I'm also not sure if this works on all major OSs. Nonetheless, if these settings work (and if they are enabled), then Step 4. is indeed superfluous:)

Comment: Just wanted to pass on a huge thank you! I spent hours trying to get this working on my own then found your answer and it was exactly what I needed

Comment: @amura.cxg Happy to hear it's useful and thanks for making my day!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error by running "Run AutoSSL" on my hosting cPanel **after** DNS propagation.

Now Firefox says that the connection is secure, without any error.