Self-Signed certificate that works with Android AND Firefox
All resources at home are behind a VPN, I don't "require" SSL but vast majority of clients (web app or mobile apps) now require it, so I set up a self signed CA certificate for all services hosted on my local server using this guide https://github.com/ouaibe/howto/blob/master/HomeAssistant/HomeAssistantTrustedSelfSigned.md.
Everything went well, I was able to create the cert, update my server and my clients (chrome, android) with the new certificate.
I recently decided to switch to Firefox over chrome (cf ManifestoV3 debate) but Firefox does not have the same policy for self-signed certificates and it does not accept my certificate.
I have this error while trying to access some resources over HTTPS in my house : MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_CA_CERT_USED_AS_END_ENTITY
Problem is :

Android require CA:TRUE in basicConstraints
Firefox require CA:FALSE (https://stackoverflow.com/a/77009337/783962)

Is there a world where I can use the same self signed certificate on my android device and on my laptop with firefox/ubuntu ?
Thanks !

The guide you reference explains how to create a CA and use this CA to create leaf certificates for servers. The CA (with CA:true) should be added as trusted CA - but not be used as a leaf certificate in the browser. In the server you should use the leaf certificate which should not have CA:true. So my guess is that you somehow follow this guide wrong, like using the CA certificate for the server.

@SteffenUllrich thx for your comment. I created a root certificate (ecca.crt) and then a "leaf" for my server (server.crt). But to allow my device to acces my server and Trust their certificate, I have to add the Root Certificate on them (part 5 and 6).
Everything worked well on my laptop with Chrome (and edge - chromium based) and on my android with chrome (and with native HomeAssistant app because the cert is added globally in Android)
But when I switched to firefox few days ago, I found that Firefox does not accept certificate with CA:TRUE while android require it...

" Firefox does not accept certificate with CA:TRUE while android require it." - sure Firefox accepts importing a CA certificate. But you have to actually import it as a CA certificate, not a server certificate, personal certificate etc. Also, you have to use the server certificate for the server, not the CA certificate. Again, it is not clear enough what you actually did.
