# Angular project with self-signed certificate chain

Tags: angular, ssl, ca, self-signed-certificate

Basically, I want to add a self-signed certificate (including complete chain with own CA and intermediate) to my Angular environment. The environment is reachable via *pcname.fritz.box*. That's the idea.

Now I created my [own CA and intermediate certificates](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/openssl-create-certificate-chain-linux/) and the [server/client certificates](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/openssl-create-client-server-certificate/). Afterwards, I added the `ca-chain-bundle.cert.pem` to my `Windows 10` root CAs.

Then I added the `server.cert.pem` and `server.key.pem` to my `angular.json` and started with `ng serve --host pcsname.fritz.box --ssl`.

If I open the URL `https://pcname.fritz.box:4200/` with *Firefox* I get in the developer console `MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT` and in *Chrome*/*Edge* I get `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`.

What I'm missing? I don't want to add it as an exception. Instead it should appear as valid certificate locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were several issues:

1. I used the wrong key combination with the server certificate. Therefore the browser displayed me `CN=localhost` instead of `CN=pcname.fritz.box`.
2. Firefox needs to change some [setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44789243/426227) to accept certificates from the Windows certificate store.
3. Chrome needs a certificate with [a SAN](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/openssl-generate-csr-create-san-certificate/)!
4. Don't know if necessary, but I added all certificates (root CA, intermediate and server) to my Windows root CA store.